# Returning empty response api Rest call

Tags: angularjs, json, rest, ionic-framework

this is the response when i use Postman to test the api

```
{
"result": "OK",
"count": 1,
"content": [
    {
        "PID": 163441,
        "Barcode": "TAILLES_TDET",
        "Couleur": "",
        "Taille": "\u001f6/8-4XS",
        "Gencod": "1000001311111",
        "RefFournisseur": "",
        "Designation": "",
        "Saison": "",
        "Famille": "",
        "Marque": ""
    }

   ]
}
```

but when i make a $http.get call I got an error.
I think that the problem is

```
"Taille": "\u001f6/8-4XS"
```

because with other data it works the only difference is the value of that field

Comment: What are you exactly doing ? Can you share some code ? What is the message error and what are you expecting ?

Comment: it's a simple $http.get(uri).then(function(result) {
   alert(JSON.stringify(result))
},function(error){alert(JSON.stringify(result))}); I expect the same response as Postman but i get {}

Comment: Have you debugged it in chrome? Try var obj = {"JObject" : result}; var json = JSON.stringify(obj);